# Authentication between client mobile app and backend server - Openid Connect

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, openid-connect

We did some research regarding the best SSO solution for native apps and found out that OpenID connect works great for mobile solutions.
We tried an iOS library [AppAuth](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/) as a client SDK for communicating with OAuth 2.0 and [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) providers. This solution requires a client to be signed up with the IDP server before it can request tokens from it.
OpenID Connect library returns access token for authorization grant and id token encoded in a secure JSON Web Token (JWT).
My question is how the authentication will be between client mobile application and the client backend server.
Can we use the JWT for web service authentication? The client backend server should validate the JWT token based on some pre-requisitions like OP issuer, the registered Client ID,  ID token JWS algorithm...
Correct me if I have miss-understanding and please prove the answer with some links as references if possible.